# getOwner method does not return value

Tags: java

Hey stackoverflow community!

Kind of a newcomer to coding, so please go easy on me.

Basically I'm trying to get this code to return the **owner** when I call the **getOwner** method.
All of this is in java!

Here's my code:

```
public class SmartCard<__name__> {
    public __name__ owner;
    public __name__ getOwner(){
        return owner;
    }
}
```

Am I approaching this the wrong way?
Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Are you looking for a data type to use? `String` comes to mind. You need to initialize your class' field.

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to guess that the reason it's not getting returned means that `getOwner` returns null.  That's because you haven't initialized `owner` to anything.  This *might* be how you can do that:

```
public class SmartCard<__name__> {
    public __name__ owner = new __name__();
    public __name__ getOwner(){
        return owner;
    }
}
```

I say "might" because I don't know what `__name__` is or how it can be initialized.  This would be a good opportunity to learn about nulls and [null pointer exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception).

BTW, you should be aware that `__name__` doesn't follow the [java style guidelines](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html).